# Заменить значение переменнй в файле с помощью регулярного выражения в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать замену значения переменной в файле с помощью регулярного выражения,чтобы значение LISTUSER = "123456abcd" менялось на другое значение, например "55555", при этом, значение которое присвоено LISTUSER - не известно(поиск по шаблону не получится)

Comment: Именно с помощью регулярного выражения надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
import re

text="""
line 1
LISTUSER = "123456abcd"
line N
"""

new_val = '"55555"'

res = re.sub(r'(\bLISTUSER\s*=\s*)(\"[^"]*\")', rf'\1{new_val}', text)


print(res)
```

Вывод на экран:

```
line 1
LISTUSER = "55555"
line N
```

Answer (score 1):

С исходным кодом лучше работать как с кодом, а не как с текстом. Тем более, что у вас уже есть парсер и лексер, способные проанализировать исходник на много лучше, чем это способны сделать регулярные выражения. В следующем примере исходный код разбирается в [абстрактное синтаксическое дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), которое уже модифицируется:

```
import ast
import astor

class AssignChanger(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        if any(t.id == 'LISTUSER' for t in node.targets):
            node.value, old_val = ast.Str(s='55555'), node.value
            ast.copy_location(node.value, old_val)
        return node


with open('source.py', encoding='utf-8') as in_fh:
    tree = ast.parse(in_fh.read())
    AssignChanger().visit(tree)

    # Можно модифицированный код сразу выполнить
    code = compile(tree, filename='source.py', mode='exec')
    exec(code)

    # Или сохранить в файл
    with open('modified.py', encoding='utf-8') as out_fh:
        out_fh.write(astor.to_source(tree))
```